# ThreadLocal variable is not changed

Tags: java, multithreading, simpledateformat, thread-local

I have the below given code which is using ThreadLocal to store a separate copy of SimpleDateFormat per thread. The initial pattern I have is MM/dd/yyyy.

```
class PerThreadLocalVariables {
   public static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> THREAD_LOCAL_FORMATTER = ThreadLocal
        .withInitial(() -> new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```

I have the following task 'TransactionService' which is using ThreadLocal instance to log the start date of the txn. This class also has a method to change the SimpleDateFormat for a particular task -

```
class TransactionService implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": startDate= "
            + PerThreadLocalVariables.THREAD_LOCAL_FORMATTER.get().format(new Date()));

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("After some time ... " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": date pattern= "
                + PerThreadLocalVariables.THREAD_LOCAL_FORMATTER.get().toPattern());

    }
    catch( InterruptedException e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public void changeFormatterToYYYMMDD()
  {
    // Changing the thread local variable will not affect variable of other thread.
    PerThreadLocalVariables.THREAD_LOCAL_FORMATTER.set(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"));
  }
}
```

Now in the main method I am creating three threads and starting them, For first thread (thread-1) I am changing the SimpleDateFormat pattern to yyyy/MM/dd. So as per ThreadLocal concept changing this should not affect the pattern used by other two threads (thread-2 and thread-3). But the problem is it is not even changing the pattern for thread-1. Still I see the initial pattern i.e. MM/dd/yyyy. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here-

```
public class ThreadLocalDemo {

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
  {
    TransactionService txn1 = new TransactionService();
    new Thread(txn1, "thread-1").start();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    new Thread(new TransactionService(), "thread-2").start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new Thread(new TransactionService(), "thread-3").start();

    txn1.changeFormatterToYYYMMDD(); // this will not affect thread-2 and thread-3's simpleDateFormat pattern
    System.out.println("Changed SimpleDateFormat pattern to yyyy/MM/dd for thread-1");

  }
}
```

output - (you can see still the pattern for thread-1 is the same i.e. MM/dd/yyyy, it should have changed to yyyy/MM/dd as per the code)

```
thread-1: startDate= 11/25/2019
thread-2: startDate= 11/25/2019
Changed SimpleDateFormat pattern to yyyy/MM/dd for thread-1
thread-3: startDate= 11/25/2019
After some time ... thread-1: date pattern= MM/dd/yyyy
After some time ... thread-2: date pattern= MM/dd/yyyy
After some time ... thread-3: date pattern= MM/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Don't use it. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. They are akso threadsafe, so no need for your thread-local. One global `DateTimeFormatter` will do provided that you want the same format everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For first thread (thread-1) I am changing the SimpleDateFormat pattern to yyyy/MM/dd.

No you're not.

You're calling `txn1.changeFormatterToYYYMMDD()` in the *main* thread. That's not `thread-1`. You have *four* threads in total: the thread executing the `main` method, and three threads that you've created separately.

So the only pattern that you're changing is one that is never logged.

Comment: Ohh. I see it is actually changing the pattern for Main thread. Thanks for pointing that. But now the question is how to change pattern for thread-1 after it started?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. This is not possible outside of thread because one thread can not see threadLocal variable of other thread. This is the reason changing the pattern from main thread was actually referring the thread-local of main thread only not the thread-1. Thanks bro for clarification.